# Tradeview alerts are acting differently than plotshape

Tags: pine-script, alerts

I'm testing tradeview to make custom alerts, but I have no idea why the alerts are acting differently with plotshape's.

Alert are set with the once per bar-setting, so I assume it check variables after the candle

```
plotshape(closeLong == true,style=shape.triangleup, text="CLOSE LONG", location=location.belowbar, color=color.white, size=size.small)
plotshape(closeShort == true,style=shape.triangledown, text="CLOSE SHORT",color=color.white, size=size.small)
alertcondition(closeLong == true, title='Close Long Signal', message='Close Long Signal Alert')
alertcondition(closeShort == true, title='Close Short Signal', message='Close Short Signal Alert')

plotshape(currentAction == 1,style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(currentAction == -1,style=shape.triangledown, text="SELL",color=color.red, size=size.small)

alertcondition(currentAction == 1, title='Buy Signal', message='Buy Signal Alert')
alertcondition(currentAction == -1, title='Sell Signal', message='Sell Signal Alert')
```

Plotshape work correctly but alerts sometimes tickers and mostly not.

Comment: Seems that the problem might be in the result calculations;
[link] (https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Indicator_repainting) (point 2)

Comment: Any idea of how to make sure the ema/time frame settings are the same with alerts and the chart?